# Overlay on map as a polygon is added successfully, but i cant remove that polygon in my ios 8 device

Tags: ios, mkmapview, overlay, mkpolygon

```
Add overlays
    myPolygon=[MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:numberOfPoints];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:myPolygon];


remove overlay
    [self.mapView removeOverlay:myPolygon];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call removeOverlays:, the map view will release the MKOverlay and MKOverlayView objects.

You hold your own references to these in myPolygon.

```
if (myPolygon != nil) {
    [myPolygon release];  // <-- remove this
    myPolygon = nil;
}

if (myPolygon != nil) {
    [myPolygon release];  // <-- remove this
    myPolygon = nil;
}
```

OR

```
for (id<MKOverlay> overlayToRemove in mapView.overlays)
{
   if ([myPolygon isKindOfClass:[OverlayClassToRemove class]])
   {
       [mapView removeOverlay:myPolygon];
   }
}
```